# Android code: convert space keycode to % keycode on keypress device keyboard

Tags: android, keycode

I am trying to change space to % in my android code. My aim is like this:

when user writes  for example  "**I am trying**", after press spacebar instead a gap between words a % be written in myeditText; I mean like this: "I%am%trying"

Comment: It's Simple... Just listen for `keyup` event on Activity/Fragment or the `EditText` where you want the text to appear.. For more Info you should see: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305972/edittext-onkeydown)

Answer (score 0):

Just implement a **TextWatcher** on your editText and inside its **onTextChanged()** method implements a simple if condition to check if space is entered or not and then replace that space with % if the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
                editText.setText(charSequence.toString().replace(" ", "%"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for Answer. I used that but when I press first space, replace " " to "%" but when press another " " there is no feedback

Comment: no. when i write for example "I am trying" , there is no any change and doesnt come % after push space key